# What is the point of StringForm?

Tags: functions, string-manipulation, core-language, language-design, function-comparison

I never really understood the point of `StringForm` returning a `StringForm` rather than a `String`, which was always either irrelevant to me or an annoyance (addressed by `ToString`).  `Mathematica` 10 introduced `TemplateApply`, which seems to offer the same functionality (since it can work directly with a string) but returns a `String`.  So my question: are there situations where `StringForm` remains useful, or should it be abandoned?

Comment: `StringForm` can produce results that contain nicely formatted forms of arbitrary mathematica expressions. I dont see how you readily get similar results with string templates.

Comment: @george2079 `InsertionFunction->ToString@*StandardForm` ... which reminds me, I find the default behavior (provided by `TextString`) to be quite an odd choice for the insertion function.

Comment: I suspect that this will be down to opinion and personal philosophy.  It follows other `*Form` functions in behaviour: it just *looks* like a string, but the underlying expression has head `StringForm` and preserves its arguments. The same is true for `InputForm`, `MatrixForm`, `FullForm`, etc. There were lots of changes in v10, maybe this philosophy is changing, perhaps to make Mathematica more like other systems or be more compatible with other systems.  `ToString@StringForm[...]` was common before.  The one prominent use of StringForm I know of is in message formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that [`Message` returns `StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html):

> `Message[mname, e1, e2, …]` is printed as `StringForm[mess, e1, e2, …]` where *`mess`* is the value of the message *`mname`*. Entries of the form  *`` `i` ``* in the string *`mess`* are replaced by the corresponding *`ei`*.

`StringForm` is a container that keeps the supplied arguments what makes it easy to extract them for the purposes of debugging. `TemplateApply` is intended for convenient generation of standardized output, not for debugging.